# Unable to manipulate html element CSS property after load from separate html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Beginner to javascript and web development here. I have the following code. I am trying to manipulate the css for the #blog_nav element, but I am unable to get anything to render. A call to `$("#blog_nav).length` returns 0, which makes me believe the element does not yet exist for some reason. When I call `$("#" + selected_page + "_nav").css("color": "red")` in the inspect console after the page has loaded, it works fine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>title</title>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/site_navigation.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <aside id="right_container"></aside>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            loadSideNav("blog");
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

`site_navigation.js`

```
function loadSideNav(selected_page) {
    $("#right_container").load("components.html #side_nav");
    console.log($('#blog_nav').length); // returns 0
    $("#" + selected_page + "_nav").css("color": "red"); // doesn't work
}
```

`components.html`

```
<nav id="side_nav">
    <ul id="side_nav_list">
        <li><a id="blog_nav" class="nav_link" href="index.html">blog</a></li>
        <li><a id="projects_nav" class="nav_link" href="index.html">projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to wait for the asynchronous `.load` to complete - at the time you call `$("#" + selected_page + "_nav").css`, the network request is still pending

Comment: That was it! Used the load callback function and put my css manipulation code in there. Thank you